# Why is my 'nav' so wide on my webpage?

Tags: html, css

Here is a screenshot of the page
[image]

And I can't, for the life of me, figure out why my nav is so damn wide when I've set it to only 5% width?

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <header>Browyer Realty</header>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home Page</li>
                <li>Residential</li>
                <li>Business</li>
                <li>Properties</li>
                <li>Rentals</li>
                <li>Appraisals</li>
                <li>Contact Us</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <article>
            <h2>Listing 2048</h2>
            <p>
                Paragraph 1
            </p>
            <p>
                Paragraph 2
            </p>
            <p>
                Paragraph 3
            </p>
        </article>

        <section>
            <img alt="img" src="img01.jpg">
        </section>
        <section>
            <img alt="img2" src="img02.jpg">
        </section>

        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
div.container {
    width: 100%;
}

header,footer {
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    clear: left;
}

footer {
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    float: left;
    width: 5%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 20%;
}

nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

article {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25%; 
    width: 30%;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

section {
    margin-left: 50%;
    top: 0;
}
```

So as you can see from the code, I have set 'nav' width to only 5%, but you can clearly see on the screenshot of my page that its width is more like 35%. I'm not sure what is causing this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the code as actual code instead of images? It makes it much easier for other developers to reproduce the issue and to find a solution.

Comment: @LiamEmery  Please post your code rather than posting a screenshot of your code.

Comment: We can't help you with just some images of code. Please provide a Minimal, complete html and css code

Comment: sure, sorry about that

Comment: At SO we prefer actual code over pictures of code.

Comment: @LiamEmery Your `nav` is only 5% of the container. I would suggest you to inspect the `nav` element in your Developer toold.

Comment: why all the down votes? I don't see anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @ArunKumar the container has 100% width of the page though, so effectively, that 5% width on the nav is 5% width of the whole page

Answer (score 1):

It is **already 5% wide**, it will be visible if you apply **overflow** property.

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

Comment: OP has question why it look wide? : it look wide because next element has left-margin but in actual "NAV" is not wide, it only 5% width

Answer (score -1):

The width of the nav is **5%** only you can check it by giving border :

```
1px solid blue
```

But if you are asking why the text is coming out of it then it is because of the padding applied in nav ul & nav in css if you make them zero then the text fits in **5% width only**